# Как правильно форкнуть процесс в flask?

Tags: python, nginx, flask

Стоит задача сделать API, под которым будет запускаться скрипт, который в свою очередь может выполняться очень и очень долго -  от 90 секунд. API, как можно догадаться, должен отвечать моментально.

В качестве веб-севера будет выступать `nginx` с `proxy` на `flask` апликацию.
Как удалось выяснить, `flask` совсем не асинхронный.

Сразу возникала идея форкнуться и выполнять задачу в фоне.

Накидал для пробы:

```
def start():
    pid1 = os.fork()
    if pid1 == 0:
        os.setsid()
        x = 30
        while x > 0:
            sleep(1)
            with open('/tmp/sleep.log', 'a') as fd:
                pid = str(os.getpid())
                print "child pid = ", pid 
                fd.write(pid  + ' PID \n')
            x -= 1
        os._exit(0)
    else:
        print os.getpid()
        while True:
            pass
start()
```

В этом примере все замечательно работает. Создается новый процесс, задачка выполнятся в фоне. После завершения дочерний процесс умирает, родительский продолжает работать.

Попробовал перенести под `flask`:

```
@app.route('/api/start', methods=['POST'])
def start():
    d1 = "DONE\n"
    pid1 = os.fork()
    if pid1 == 0:
        os.setsid()
        closer() #здесь закрываю все файловые дескрипторы унаследованные от родителя
        x = 30
        while x > 0:
            sleep(1)
            with open('/tmp/sleep.log', 'a') as fd:
                pid = str(os.getpid())
                print "child pid = ", pid 
                fd.write(pid  + ' PID \n')
            x -= 1
        os._exit(0)
    else:
        print os.getpid()
    return d1
```

Вот что происходит в этом примере:

```
username    6158  0.0  0.4 106528 26192 ?        S    19:34   0:00 python -u /home/username/VCS/username/seek/lui/tcpdumper/dumper_api.py
username    6165  0.3  0.4 182876 26816 ?        Sl   19:34   0:05 /usr/bin/python /home/username/VCS/username/seek/lui/tcpdumper/dumper_api.py
username    6262  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Zs   19:34   0:00 [python] <defunct>
```

Дочерний процесс сразу становится зомби. Соответственно, в файл ничего не записывается.

Собственно, главный вопрос в том, почему так происходит.

Подскажите, какие еще варианты решения проблемы могут мне подойти.
Смотрел в сторону `Tornado`, `subprocess` (его использовать *нежелательно*).
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Удалось разобраться в проблеме. Может быть кому-нибудь поможет.

Дело в том, что родительский процесс ждет завершения дочернего ( код возврата ).
Я думал, что вызова os._exit() достаточно и это можно увидеть запустив strace:

`16059 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=16060, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---`

Оказалось, что есть нюансы. 
Нюанс заключается в следующем. Для родительского процесса нужно установить обработчик сигнала. Сделать это можно использовав библиотеку signal.

`signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, signal.SIG_IGN)`

Первый аргумент - int'вая константа, а второй - действия для сигнала.
После завершения дочернего процесса он уходит в состоянии зомби ( это нормально ), как было в моем случаем. 
После установки обработчика начинает работать механизм reaping и OS самостоятельно очищает таблицу процессов.

Кстати, на stackoverflow предложили достаточно хорошее решение.
Идея заключается, в том, чтобы сделать демона, который будет смотреть в очередь задач. При этом веб-сервер будет отвечать 202 кодом. Задачки будут разбираться по мере поступления, а статут задачи всегда можно будет узнать по другому URL.